# Calculate energy-density of known plasma in microwave?

Tags: energy, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, plasma-physics

Let's assume I want to create a plasma in a regular household microwave similar to this [home-made experiment](https://youtu.be/G7lfzA7WzVI?t=1m26s). Although I am dealing with a small amount of mass, I assume that the addition of microwave fields greatly add to the energy of the plasma.

How would I calculate the energy-density of the plasma in terms of Einstein's energy-density equation $T$?

What isn't clear to me is how the microwaves contribute towards the energy. Do I need to re-think this in terms of magnetohydrodynamics?

Assumptions:

- only need to energy-density at a point in time $t$
- composition, temperature, exact electron/ion/particle densities of plasma is determinable and constant
- energy contributed to plasma from microwaves is constant and determinable

Thank you to those who can help.